# Eclipse p2 touchpoint copy from jar

Tags: java, eclipse, copy, action, p2

I need to copy file in the configure phase which is located in jar to a folder but I am not sure what is the right way to do it and if it even possible.
Here is what I have in my p2.inf file:

```
instructions.configure = \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.copy(source:${artifact.location}/res/np.sys, target:D:/np.sys, overwrite:true);
```

My file is located in the jar -> res/np.sys but with that I have IOException that the file do not exists

```
 Source: d:\Program Files\Test Program\plugins\com.vendor.testprogram.p2.installaction_1.0.0.201707210555.jar\res\np.sysdoes not exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to have the JAR unpacked by the installation of the product, either by:

- adding the plugin to a feature with `"Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation"` checked, or
- directly within the plugin's `MANIFEST.MF` file with `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir`

The copy will then be successful.